# Scalatest Matcher - Check single value exists in a set of values

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am generating a value, and I know the possible values it could be. I want to write this

```
val myInt = someFunction()
myInt shouldBe oneOf (1, 2, 3)
```

However this doesn't seem to work for me as of Scalatest 3 M15. My workaround is

```
List(myValue) should contain atMostOneOf (1, 2, 3)
```

Which is a lot more confusing to read and understand.

Is there a way to do what I want here? It seems like a common scenario.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It compiles but I get the test failure `1 was not equal to oneOf (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: You are certain about the correct type of myInt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`oneOf` can only be used to compare contents of collections. You can use `Some` as a simple one-element collection:

```
Some(myInt) should contain oneOf (1, 2, 3)
```

Alternatively:

```
myInt should (equal(1) or equal(2) or equal(3))
```

Comment: I guess the latter option is at least not confusing. Thanks.